# Menu for all posts from multiple categories

Tags: posts, categories, menus

This seems like a basic question but I couldn't find answer anywhere.
I have 300+ posts and 15+ categories on my website and I'm unable to create a menu to link to all the posts from all categories.

I would like to show all the 300+ posts (with pagination of course) from all categories when someone clicks on "Blog" menu without having to create 15+ sub-menu dropdown for the 15+ categories. How can I achieve this?

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: Default WordPress behavior is to output all posts regardless of category on whichever page is set as the posts-page in wp-admin. If Blog is a post-category then it would potentially work against this behavior. Can you provide more context regarding how your site is configured? Thanks!

Comment: Further reading about the posts page, https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/settings-reading-screen/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.